# vaadin designer layout component in eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, vaadin, vaadin7

I am new in vaadin framework.

Vaadin with eclipse for vaadin designer is not working properly, while i am dragging new component layout it going to hang my eclipse.

Can anyone help me why this happen?

Any solution for this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should had some of your code to help others helping you.

Comment: the not of code issue designer vaadin in eclipse didnt take any layout via  desgin  page , it will take two component and then vaadin desginer will stop again after 20 min or more vaadin designer take the componenet layou t

Comment: the time is more taken to  make the page through vaadin designer

Comment: if the CPU spikes there is a good chance, that its GC and you need more RAM assigned (plain guesswork from the information!).  also the designer is licensed software and you might be better off asking the support?

Comment: Is it an option for you to upgrade to Eclipse Mars.1? Your information is not enough to analyze it, but I had several issues with the Vaadin plugins in Luna. After switching to Mars.1, my issues disappear (at the same time, our team also switched to Java 8, which also could be a reason for the improved behaviour). Could you try this and tell us, if the behaviour is the same? Also, information about your OS/platform, available memory for eclipse and the log files for eclipse could help a lot.